# Need to understand why adding a dummy function for disabled property is checking for required fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, react-bootstrap

We have form in our tool. We have added the required flag for the necessary input fields. However, despite this , it allows save button to work without checking the required fields.

Example:
One component of CreateForm.js is as follows(just added one input here of Name):

```
import { Form, Row, Col, InputGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';

...
...
return (
        <>

            <Form.Group as={Row}>
                <Form.Label className="text-left ml-5" column sm="3">Name</Form.Label>
                <Col sm="5">
                    <InputGroup hasValidation>
                        <Form.Control
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        placeholder="Provide a Name"
                        onChange={e => handleInputChange(e)}
                        value={props.commonSource.name}
                        required
                        isInvalid={(props.commonSource.name).trim() === '' ? true : false}
                        />
                        <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                            Provide a appropriate name for your workflow.
                        </Form.Control.Feedback>
                    </InputGroup>
                </Col>
            </Form.Group>
 </>
    );
};
```

NewForm.js where it is called:

```
<CreateForm 
...
...
/>

 <CustomButton
 save={e => saveData(e)}
 disable = {checkRequiredFormFields}
 />
```

CustomButton.js code:

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

const CustomButton = (props) => {

    return (
        <>
        {props.save ? 
            <Button 
            className={className}
            id="button_success"
            type="submit"
            onClick={e => props.save(e)}
            disabled={props.disable ? props.disable : false}
            >
                Save
            </Button>
        :
            <Button 
            className="button btn btn-sm mr-2" 
            id="button_error"
            onClick={() => props.back()}
            disabled={props.disable ? props.disable : false}
            >
                {props.text ? props.text : 'Back'}
            </Button>
        }
        </>
    );
};
```

Current behaviour:
With above code, the input field gets highlighted in red for Name with a message `Provide a appropriate name for your workflow` when i don't give any input but the save button works still wherein the form gets saved with empty input.

Expected behaviour:
The save should not work unless the required fields are filled.

What i did was i thought i will add a function to check the values of those input field and return true or false to the disable attribute of button. However, I am getting the functionality working for a dummy function with no value or action i.e save doesn't work till all the required fields have been filled up. Button is not disabled but it will take you to the field which is pending still and ask to fill it up(WHICH IS WHAT I WANT) but i want to understand how this function with nothing in it is fulfilling this requirement logically. Please see my code:

NewForm.js

```
    const checkRequiredFormFields = () => {
        // console.log("testing disable");
        // return false;
        // has only commented code but adding this function, the save will ask for all required fields.
    }




...
....

                            <div className="modal_buttons_div">
                                <div className="modal_buttons">
                                    <CustomButton
                                    save={e => saveData(e)}
                                    disable = {checkRequiredFormFields}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

ASK: Can someone please help me understand how this function with no value or useful statements is helping achieve my requirement? NOTE: If i replace the function name with boolean value(true/false) or string, i dont get it same.

I want this functionality itself but would like to have an understanding.
Thanks